# Does incomplete combustion produce carbon dioxide at first?

Tags: combustion, hydrocarbons

I know that the incomplete combustion of a hydrocarbon produces $\ce{CO}$ or sometimes $\ce{C}$ if the amount of oxygen is very limited, but I was wondering if at first $\ce{CO2}$ is produced and only when there isn't enough oxygen, then $\ce{CO}$ and C are produced? Or is only $\ce{CO}$ and $\ce{C}$ produced from the beginning of the reaction?

My question if the answer is the latter case would be how would the reaction 'know' right from the start that there isn't enough oxygen?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/150266/ratio-of-carbon-monoxide-and-carbon-dioxide-when-carbon-and-oxygen-are-made-to-r/150267#150267

Comment: Also: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57423/incomplete-combustion?r=SearchResults

Comment: The link to look at is that given by Safari Faisal